# Is it possible to send text files to a peripheral device using CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I want to develop an iOS app to control our device. So in our case, the iPhone(Central) has to send a text file(it's a configuration file) to our device(Peripheral). Is it possible ?

I checked the Apple Core Bluetooth Programming Guide, I don't see examples fit my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GATT profile, which Core Bluetooth exposes, is able to send and receive raw data.

While there may be standard profiles built on top of the GATT profile that make file transfer easier, Core Bluetooth does not have built in support for these. You will have to implement any profiles above GATT on your own, or possibly find a third party library.

For some other (non BLE) profile support, use the [ExternalAccessory](https://developer.apple.com/reference/externalaccessory) framework.